# ngx-swiper hides the popup inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, swiper.js

[Link for stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swipper-pagination-7y6hun?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Above is the link for sample application, I am trying to show popup which is inside the swiper so I used overflow:visible but it disturbs the swiper slide. Please let me know how can I fix it

There are three slides, I am showing one slide at a time and out 3, 1 slide have a popup link, click on link it will open the popup, but since that popup link is inside the swiper, so its hidden with swiper div. Overflow:visible, works for me to display the link of popup properly but it starts showing two slides

```
  .swiper.activeIndex{
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
```

Above code causing issues to the other slides

Comment: what do you mean by it is distrubing?

Comment: instead of one slide at a time, its showing two slides on load. can you open stackblitz link? I am facing issue there

Comment: @Chellappan updated the question for better understanding, hope I will get my solution soon

Comment: i think the stackblitz working fine

Comment: @Chellappan yeah, but its showing two slides

Answer (score 0):

Since you added swiper class visible !important the hidden divs are being displayed remove that code and use transform:translate to move your tool tip

---

```
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible !important;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    transform: translate(10px,4px);
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

Your Forked example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/swipper-pagination-vftiby

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/swipper-pagination-f41cfu?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: popup height and width is being reduced, I was trying show popup overlaying the swiper